# Python Pprint Pformat to return HTML string instead of regular string

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, pprint

I know we can use pformat to return a formated string of a dictionary in python, but it's not in html format. How can I get the html format?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly that would look like?

Comment: HTML is not a thing in python or pprint, you will need to either do the formating yourself or find a library that does it.
For example, [this answer[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297969/from-python-dictionary-to-html-list) might be a good start

Comment: I think that answer works okay. I ended up with replacing `\n` with `<br>` and it works just fine