# Convert a dictionary to html with indents

Tags: python, html, json

I to convert a dictionary `data` into html with correct indents. Currently, I use the the following approach:

```
import json
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

data = {'a': 1, 
        'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 3}}

# Convert to string
data_html = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

# Add html spaces
data_html = data_html.replace(" ", "&nbsp")

# Add html next lines 
data_html = data_html.replace("\n", "<br />\n")

display(HTML(data_html))
```

Output:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 2,
        "d": 3
    }
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve this result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: serialize a dictionary into a simple html output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930713/python-serialize-a-dictionary-into-a-simple-html-output)

Comment: Not sure "into html" applies here? That's not HTML, that's JSON appended with HTML data to make it presentable. Maybe I'm picky now. If your only goal is to present the JSON data as readable text on a website. It's either this or append `<pre>` before the block. If not, the duplicate link is invalid and you meant to do something else :)